# How can I wait until a loading mask disappears in protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I always have problems with this loading mask because sometimes it takes longer to disappear and other times it takes less time to disappear. Whenever it takes longer than normal, the test fails.

Is there a function that avoids this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it help:

```
$$('.cMiddle tr .item').get(5).isPresent().then(function(present) {
                    if (present) {
                        $$('.cMiddle tr .item').get(5).getText().then(function(dtsStatus) {
                            fs.appendFile('D:/CODE/script/script/testscript/output/Status.html', dtsStatus + '\n', 'utf8');
                        })
                    } else {
                        fs.appendFile('D:/CODE/script/script/testscript/output/Status.html', '\n', 'utf8');
                    }
                });
```